# About super-class and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, dart, superclass

```dart
void main() {
  Car myNormalCar = Car(20);

  print(myNormalCar.numberOfSeat);

  myNormalCar.drive('academia');
}

class Car {
  int numberOfSeat = 40;
  int height = 30;

  Car(int seat) {
    numberOfSeat = seat;
  }

  void drive(String name) {
    print('the wheels turn:$name');
  }
}

class ElectricCar extends Car {}
```

ElectricCar here shows that "The superclass 'Car' doesn't have a zero argument constructor". I want to assign different values for properties that has been inherited from Car for Electric Car.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of `Car` inside `ElectricCar` since you are extending from `Car`. I am not sure what you actually want but you can e.g. do the following if you want to add more properties to `ElectricCar` but still want to be able to set `numberOfSeat`:

```
class ElectricCar extends Car {
  int power;

  ElectricCar(this.power, int seat) : super(seat);
}
```

The important part is you need to call the constructor of `Car` with the constructor of `ElectricCar` since the constructor of `Car` is the code which know how to initialize the `Car` part of `ElectricCar`.

Comment: Thanks.Solved my problem.